# .NET MVC API - dots (period) in get request

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to setup Facebook Notification API.
I have an APi Controller with RealtimeUpdate() - Get, will be used just for verification of endpoint.

As is written in Fb Docs:

> Firstly, Facebook servers will make a single HTTP GET to your callback
>   URL when you try to add or modify a subscription. A query string will
>   be appended to your callback URL with the following parameters:
>
> - hub.mode - The string "subscribe" is passed in this parameter
> - hub.challenge - A random string
> - hub.verify_token - The verify_token value you specified when you created the subscription

From here I have a problem - I have no idea how to handle this dots in query params names. I google a lot, and did not find the solution.

Can somebody please say to me how to get data from this hub.* values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update your method signature using the FromUri attributes, like this:

```
public string Get(
    [FromUri(Name="hub.mode")]string mode,
    [FromUri(Name="hub.challenge")]string challenge,
    [FromUri(Name="hub.verify_token")]string verifyToken
    )
{
    /* method body */
}
```

The parameters will be bound from the query string using the specified names.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know you could do this!

Comment: For anyone accessing this topic using .Net Core, the attribute is [FromQuery] instead of [FromUri]

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different form Steve's answer.

In case you need to have a normal controller instead of an Api one (if you are inheriting from `Controller` rather tha `ApiController`), the follow worked for me:

```
 namespace Name
    {
            public class Hub
        {
            public string Mode { get; set; }

            public string Challenge { get; set; }

            // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
            public string Verify_Token { get; set; }
        }

        public class FacebookWebHooksController : Controller
        {
            [System.Web.Http.HttpGet, ActionName("Callback")]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            public ContentResult CallbackGet(Hub hub)
            {
                if (hub.Mode == "subscribe" && hub.Verify_Token == "YOUR_TOKEN")
                    return Content(hub.Challenge, "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);

                return Content(string.Empty, "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Callback()
        {
            Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Model Binder has some illegal characters, of which I believe '.' is a special character, used primarily to bind complex objects. When all else fails, you can look at Request.QueryString and Request.Form directly, just like in ASP.NET WebForms.

You can also try using a complex object that has a Property named hub with subproperties mode, challenge, and verify_token. This might just do the trick.

Comment: Model binder not working :( and Request.QueryString or .Form will also not work, cause in ApiController (I inherit my controller from that) there is the Property called Request and it does not contain .QuerySting Method

Comment: I would consider making this controller a non API controller... Or using a custom Model Binder.

Comment: Switch to Controller from ApiController helped. Now I can request QueryString and get all objects. Thanks for help! :) Any way, good idea to know how to make it in Api controller. BTW, model binding did not help :(