# Receiving incoming parameters with dots in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-web-api

[image]

Facebook wants to send the parameters as named above and in C#, we can't name variables with dots. How do I handle this in a C# web api endpoint that wants to receive these parameters? So far, my parameters have underscores causing the endpoint to not work

Comment: does this answer your question ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844491/net-mvc-api-dots-period-in-get-request

Comment: No. `FromUri` is deprecated.

Comment: in the comments it was stated that :For anyone accessing this topic using .Net Core, the attribute is [FromQuery] instead of [FromUri]

Comment: Just saw that. Let me try it out